# PHP find Exponent after remainder is zero

Tags: php, math

I have this code written but I am having little issue or might be I am missing something,

```
public function test()
{
    $number = "8192";
    for ($i=1; $i<=32; $i++)
        {
            if(($number % pow(2,$i)) == 0)
                {
                $final = 32-$i;
                echo $final;
                }
        }
    exit;
}
```

I need to get which Exponent aka $i is used and then need to minus the value from 32 (or something else) to get the final results.

Comment: if you want to stop when the condition is satisfied just use "break" in side the if statement, if you want to get all the matches store in an array

Comment: @Shan, you mean I need to use Switch Case for this?

Comment: @RizwanRanjha - No, `break` isn't limited to switch/case statements, it ends execution of the current `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do-while` or `switch` structure; so it will also terminate your `for` loop

Comment: try to add break; after :  echo $final;

Comment: @Shan, Thank you but in this case it returns 31 which is wrong answer. Expected answer is 19 as 2^13 = 8192 and 32-13 = 19.

Comment: Just change your if condition to : $number == pow(2,$i), Because the modulous operator will true for many conditions from 1 to 32

Comment: @Shan ! It works, thank you so much, can you please post so I can accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to compare the values just change the if condition, the modulus operator will not give you the exact result,
Here is the complete answer :

```
public function test()
{
    $number = "8192";
    for ($i=1; $i<=32; $i++)
        {
            if($number == pow(2,$i))
                {
                    $final = 32-$i;
                    echo $final;
                    break;
                }
        }
    exit;
}
```